# spring login script how to check the db is connected?

Tags: java, spring

i'm learning spring framework, and i created a login app according to

http://o7planning.org/web/fe/default/en/document/29799/simple-login-web-application-using-spring-mvc-spring-security-and-spring-jdbc

but when i try to login using the username & password at database, it redirects me to error, here is the xml

spring-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">


   <http use-expressions="true">
       <intercept-url pattern="/" access="isAnonymous()" />
       <intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access="isAnonymous()" />
       <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="isAnonymous()" />
       <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="isAnonymous()" />


       <intercept-url pattern="/userInfo"
           access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')" />
       <intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
       <intercept-url pattern="/other/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

       <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

       <form-login login-page='/login' login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
           default-target-url="/userInfo" always-use-default-target="false"
           authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" username-parameter="username"
           password-parameter="password" />

       <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/logoutSuccessful"
           delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" />

   </http>

   <authentication-manager>

       <!-- authentication from database -->
       <authentication-provider>
           <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="myDataSource"
               users-by-username-query="select username,password, enabled from users where username=?"
               authorities-by-username-query="select username, role from users where username=?" />
       </authentication-provider>

   </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

data-source-cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">


    <bean id="myDataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb_o7" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

i use mysql, how can i check the app is connected to DB  and retrieved the right username & password sucessfully

Comment: Hi, What's the exact error you are getting here? In normal circumstances, when application fails to connect to database, it throws JDBC or related persistance api layer error indicating the reason for failure. In case you are interested to get details of where or at which point it's failing such as network adapter failure, fail to resolve TNS or specific database error, you could change the log level to DEBUG and get the complete information.

Comment: there is no error , so i can't debug

Comment: Alright, so after login you are not being re-directed to '/userInfo'? Can you verify the URL in the browser after login where it's re-directed to and what happens if you type the above context path in the browser manually after login?

Comment: i can login if using       <authentication-provider>
           <user-service>
               <user name="user1" password="12345" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
               <user name="admin1" password="12345" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
           </user-service>
       </authentication-provider>, but not using dbuser1, if i use dbuser1, it redirects me to /login?error=true

Comment: i have removed  the xml username  & password, only try to use dbuser1

Comment: I could advise only to debug here as the url is clearly indicating that authentication has failed. It could be either due to incorrect user name & password or failure to connect to database, unless you enable debug, its quite tough to say where exactly its failing.

Comment: how to enable debug?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87808/discussion-between-shoaib-khan-and-hkguile).

Answer (score 0):

```
        <beans:bean id="customUserDetailsService"     class="com.myclass.dao.SimpleUserDetailsService"> 
     </beans:bean> 
        <authentication-manager> 
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService"> 
                <password-encoder hash="md5"> </password-encoder> 
                <!-- [plaintext, sha, sha-256, md5, md4, {sha}, {ssha}] -->
            </authentication-provider> 
    </authentication-manager> 
    <beans:bean id="authenticationFailureHandler"     class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
<beans:property name="exceptionMappings">
    <beans:props>    
    <beans:prop key="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException">/login.action?error=1</beans:prop>
    </beans:props>  
</beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

In SimpleUserDetailService for example you will test and check user from DB

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Collection;
  import java.util.List;

  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
  import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
  import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
  import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
  import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
  import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
  import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
  import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

  import UserBean;


  @Repository
  @Service
  @Transactional(readOnly=true)
  public class SimpleUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserDao userDAO;

private UserBean domainUser; 

public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    domainUser = userDAO.getUser(login);

    boolean enabled = true;
    boolean disabled = false;
    boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    boolean accountExpired = false;
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    boolean credentialsExpired = false;
    boolean accountNonLocked = true;
    boolean accountLocked = false;

    if (null != domainUser){
    return new User(
            domainUser.getUsername(), //getLogin(), 
            domainUser.getPassword(), 
            enabled, 
            accountNonExpired, 
            credentialsNonExpired, 
            accountNonLocked,
            getAuthorities(domainUser.getIduser() ) );

    } else {
        return new User(
                "**20**", 
                "**//**", 
                disabled, 
                accountExpired, 
                credentialsExpired, 
                accountLocked,
                getAuthorities(-20 ) ) ;
    }

}


public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer userid) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authList = getGrantedAuthorities(getRoles(userid));
    return authList;
}

public List<String> getRoles(Integer userid) {

    List<String> roles = new ArrayList<String>();
    roles = userDAO.getUserRoles(userid);

    return roles;
}

public static List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(List<String> roles) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

    for (String role : roles) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    }
    return authorities;
}
```

}

in userDAO.getUser(login) you select user from table_user where user_name=:login or email = :login